# The Galois group of $\bar{K}(t)/K(t)$ is isomorphic to the Galois group of $\bar{K}/K$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Consider the Galois extensions $\bar{K}/K$ and $\bar{K}(t)/K(t)$, where $\bar{K}$ is the algebraic closure of $K$. Is it true that their Galois groups are isomorphic, and if so how do we prove it? Do we need to use Hilbert's irreducibility theorem?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835986/why-is-textaut-overlinekx-mid-kx-equal-to-textaut-overlinek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the reason is nothing more than the observation that any $K$-automorphism $\overline{K} \to \overline{K}$ gives rise to a $K(t)$-automorphism $\overline{K}(t) \to \overline{K}(t)$, and any $K(t)$-automorphism $\overline{K}(t) \to \overline{K}(t)$ must send any $x \in \overline{K}$ to one of its conjugates, which must still be in $\overline{K}$, and thus gives rise to a $K$-automorphism $\overline{K} \to \overline{K}$, and this determines the $K(t)$-automorphism $\overline{K}(t) \to \overline{K}(t)$ simply because $t \in K(t)$ means that it must fix $t$.